# In singleton test container, how can we use the value inside the application.yml to do the configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, static, testcontainers

In singleton test container, i have

```
@ActiveProfiles("Testing")
@SpringBootTest
abstract class AbstractContainerBaseTest {

static final MySQLContainer MY_SQL_CONTAINER;

private static String userName;

@Value("spring.datasource.username")
public void setPrivateName(String userName) {
    AbstractContainerBaseTest.userName = userName;
}

static {
    System.out.println(userName);
    MY_SQL_CONTAINER = new MySQLContainer();
    MY_SQL_CONTAINER.start();
    }

@DynamicPropertySource
static void overrideTestProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry){
    registry.add("spring.datasource.url", mySQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.username", mySQLContainer::getUsername);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.password", mySQLContainer::getPassword);
   }
}
```

I tried to print out the username but it is always print as null, did i do anything wrong?

in application.yml, i have

```
 spring:
  profiles: Testing
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:tc:mysql:5.1.0:///test
    username: aa
    password: aa
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 20
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Ofcourse it will be `null`. The static code runs as the class is loaded into the class loader. The value is assigned after the class has been constructed and managed by Spring, long after the class has been loaded. You shouldn't be setting the properties from the file into the container, instead use the ones from the container with a dynamic property source (like you have now).

Comment: Also, try to define one method to use testcontainers. Currently, spring.datasource.url is defined using testcontainers jdbc url and also using MySQLContainer. So, choose one. Furthermore, it should be @Value("${spring.datasource.username}") instead.

Comment: As others have pointed out, omit the config file based configuration and things should become more straight forward.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry, if i really want to read the value from property file/yml file to config testcontainer and using singleton approach like above, what should i do? any keyword for me to search or some useful link foe me? i am stuck in it

Comment: I wonder why you want to preset the username? It doesn't really make sense if you can just obtain the generated user from test containers?

Comment: Since in the production profile which is in the application.yml , we are having some database params (useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci&characterEncoding=utf-8&useSSL=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true), i want to align database url param with the one we are using in production profile instead of hardcoding url param in test  container by withParam() function

Comment: Also, we need to preset database name  since our testing sql using the desired database name